# Position a plane with nodes on it so they are always in front of the camera

Tags: 3d, camera, sprite-kit, scenekit

I am trying to fix some 2D things in front of the camera so they don't move even when the camera does. I tried doing this using Sprite Kit and started wondering if this even is an appropriate approach (adding a plane with 2D nodes on it and adjusting its position when the camera moves or rotates), or is there a more straightforward (easier) approach to doing this.

I do know I can add a background to the camera but I want to be able to interact with nodes on that plane, so I guess I can't use this property.

I would appreciate any advice on how this should be done because I am new to Scene Kit and making 3D games in general.

Comment: Did you make your plane a child of your camera node? Any children of the camera will move and rotate as the camera does.

Comment: Thank you very much, completely forgot about that!